# Mysql date range query slow

Tags: mysql, performance, date, indexing

I have 2 mysql tables **spot_times - 10k rows** and **visit_times - 5.3 million rows**.

I m trying to write a query that can join `spot_times.spot_date` on `visit_times.visit_date` based on a 10 minute window.

Both date fields are indexed and column type datetime.

I have written the following sql which takes hours to run.

```
    Select spot_date, count(visit_date) total_visits
      From spot_times st 
      Left 
      Join visit_times v 
        on v.visit_date between st.spot_date and st.spot_date + interval 10 minute

    group by 1;
```

This query takes hours to run.

My explain plan looks like the query is not using the indexes.

[Explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KDFJ.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: Can you please show the database structure? For me It seems there is an issue with the visit_date index

Comment: You could also just issue an analyze table. Sometimes although you've created the index, the statistics are not updated.

Comment: Have you tried the concepts of temporary tables?

Comment: It slightly surprises me that you would want to return the entire spot_times data set

Comment: *based on a 10 minute window.* If this is often-executed task you may think about generated column (maybe virtual) and indexing it.

Comment: Your query does not have any filtering predicate. You are selecting the entire `spot_times` table. This is bound to be slow. I assume it's a batch process ran at night, so it should be fine. Because this is not for an interactive user, right?

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the comment. this is a extract of 2 month data (original data 25 million rows) from 2 different system that we want to merge and analyse. Overnight batch would be a good option however we get the spot_time data quarterly.

Comment: Are they really `DATE` datatype?  If so, adding 10 _minutes_ seems unreasonable.

Comment: Saying `LEFT JOIN` implies that you want at least 10K rows of output??  Is there no other filtering?  Perhaps you wanted a plain `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Range queries are notoriously difficult to get useful index performance with on large datasets.

You might be able to get some benefit out of partitioning `visit_times` by date range: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-range.html

Answer (score 0):

Just thought it might be useful for anyone that came across the same issue.

I started off by adding an auto_increment column `visit_id` on the `visits_times` table ordered by `visit_date` field.

Idea is to get the `visit_id` nearest to `st.spot_date` and `st.spot_date + interval 10 minute`.Then subtracting the `visit_id` which should be the total visits between the  range.

Created a function to return `visit_id` for a date and interval.Function uses the `visit_date` index and loops until it finds a record adding a second on every loop.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP function IF EXISTS `spot_time_function` //

CREATE  function `spot_time_function`( p_datetime datetime, p_time int)
returns int
BEGIN
        
declare v_id  int ;              
declare z int;         
        
set z = 0;   
    
    time_loop:  LOOP
    
    select visit_id into v_id from visit_times where visit_date = p_datetime + interval p_time minute + interval z second limit 1;
    
            IF  v_id is not null THEN 
                LEAVE  time_loop;
            END  IF;
                
            SET  z = z + 1;
        
    END LOOP;     
    
return v_id;
    
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

So final query looks like.

```
Select 
spot_date, 
spot_time_function(spot_date,10) - spot_time_function(spot_date,0) as total_visit 
From spot_times;
```

Above query runs in 0.110 sec.